# When I browse to user profiles, SharePoint tells me that there are profiles but doesn't list any of them

Tags: user-profile-service

When I navigate to the User Profile service and click "Manage User Profiles," Sharepoint tells me there are 11 profiles.  But none are listed and searches do not appear to return results.

I am having sync issues, but I don't see where that should matter.  After all, there are already 11 profiles on SharePoint.  Shouldn't I be able to see them?

On another install, I added a user profile manually.  It shows a count of 1 but doesn't actually list any profiles.

Really confused by this

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did anyone (OP, perhaps) ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

What version of SharePoint are you using?

If SharePoint 2010, you can use the following method to view list of all users.

1. Open central administration, click manage service applications under service applications,
2. Click user profile service application, then click manage user profiles,
3. Type your exact domain name in the textbox after “find profile”, then click find.
4. Check the effect.

For more information on User Profile Service administration, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721050.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Active Directory groups?

If you are then the user profile information will not show individual users from the AD group until they have contributed to the site.